LiftMaster garage door controller red and yellow light
I held on to the learn button too long and the red light above is on and it flashes with the yellow button in the center.
The control still works along with other remotes I re-programed.
It's a LiftMaster control panel with no wifi. I think it's a G885LMMC.
Any advice how to get rid of the red LED would be appreciated!

What does the Instructions say to do?   As a last resort I would unplug the opener, wait a few minutes and plug it back in.

i looked online at the manual and they dont have anything for this. It was intalled by my father a long time ago and hes no longer around so im trying to figure it out. ill see if i can unplug it somehow.
thanks for the idea!
